# In a Promise, what's the difference between using catch and the 2nd argument of then?

Tags: javascript, promise

What exactly is the difference between these two statements?

```
funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => { /* success */ })
  .catch(() => { /* fail */ });


funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => { /* success */ }, () => { /* fail */ });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises has much better detail & answer, BUT I'm thankful for this one because it perfectly matches how I would formulate the question :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides `.catch(fn)` being a shortcut for `.then(null, fn)`, the difference in your examples is that

```
funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => { /* success */ })
  .catch(() => { /* fail */ });

// is equivalent to

const p1 = funcThatReturnsAPromise()
const p2 = p1.then(() => { /* success */ })
const p3 = p2.catch(() => { /* 
   executed if p1 is rejected
   executed if p2 is rejected 
*/ })
```

While the second one is

```
funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => { /* success */ }, () => { /* fail */ });

// equivalent to

const p1 = funcThatReturnsAPromise()
const p2 = p1.then(
  () => { /* success */ },
  () => { /*
     executed if p1 is rejected
     (p2 will be actually resolved by the result of this function only when p1 is rejected)
  */ }
);
```

Comment: thank you for explaining I was just trying to find documentation regarding that how it is beneficial, If I pass error function in .then() 2nd argument

Comment: `.catch(fn)` is equal to `.then(undefined, fn)` not `.then(null, fn)`.

Comment: I checked this implementation https://github.com/then/promise/blob/master/src/es6-extensions.js#L117-L119 and it's null, regardless the spec https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method says that it could be anything but a function

Answer (score 11):

`.catch(foo)` is equal to `.then(undefined, foo)`

But there is a difference between your code samples:

```
funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => { /* success case of funcThatReturnsAPromise */ })
  .catch(() => { /* both fail case of funcThatReturnsAPromise 
                     and fail case of "then" function */ });


funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(() => { /* success case of funcThatReturnsAPromise */ }, 
        () => { /* fail case of funcThatReturnsAPromise */ });
```

Comment: second argument of .then is triggered also when .then's first argument throws an error

Comment: No, @koo. It does not. Please check jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xopaqov/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4):

> then(..) takes one or two parameters, the first for the fulfillment
>   callback, and the second for the rejection callback. If either is
>   omitted or is otherwise passed as a non-function value, a default
>   callback is substituted respectively. The default fulfillment callback
>   simply passes the message along, while the default rejection callback
>   simply rethrows (propagates) the error reason it receives. catch(..)
>   takes only the rejection callback as a parameter, and automatically
>   substitutes the default fulfillment callback, as just discussed. In other words, it’s equivalent to then(null,..) :

```
p . then ( fulfilled );
p . then ( fulfilled , rejected );
p . catch ( rejected ); // or `p.then( null, rejected )`
```

> then(..) and catch(..) also create and return a new promise, which can
>   be used to express Promise chain flow control. If the fulfillment or
>   rejection callbacks have an exception thrown, the returned promise is
>   rejected. If either callback returns an immediate, non-Promise,
>   non-thenable value, that value is set as the fulfillment for the
>   returned promise. If the fulfillment handler specifically returns a
>   promise or thenable value, that value is unwrapped and becomes the
>   resolution of the returned promise.

*—from "You Don't Know JS, Kyle Simpson*